# Displaying and manipulating updated image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, jframe, image-scaling

This program should first open an image, and then allow it to be manipulated via grayscale, scale, and rotate methods (not functional at the moment; disregard it). However, I'm not sure how I can call upon the updated image every time a method is performed. For example, if I grayscale an image, it goes to grayscale. But if I then scale it to a different size, the resulting image is a scaled version of the original image, not a scaled grayscale image. I tried putting in "image2 = image;" to no avail. How can I fix this? 
Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Picture{
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();    
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Edit Image");    
    Container content;
    static BufferedImage image;
    BufferedImage image2;
    JLabel imageLabel;

    public Picture() {
        //asks for image file as input
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose an image file to begin:");
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        if (fileChooser.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            try {
                //reads File as image
                image = ImageIO.read(selectedFile);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid image file: " + selectedFile);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No File Selected!");
        }
    }

    public int width() {
        //returns width of present image
        int width = image.getWidth();
        return width;
    }

    public int height() {
        //returns height of present image
        int height = image.getHeight();
        return height;
    }

    public void getImage() {
        this.image2 = image;
    }

    public void saveImage() {
        //saves current image as JPEG
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Save this image?");
        fileChooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
        try {
            //writes new file
            ImageIO.write(this.image, "JPG", fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println("Saving failed! Could not save image.");
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        //set frame title, set it visible, etc
        content = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //add the image to the frame
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);
        frame.setContentPane(imageLabel);

        //add a menubar on the frame with a single option: saving the image
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JMenu progName = new JMenu("Edit Image");
        progName.setBackground(Color.RED);
        menuBar.add(progName);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        ImageIcon exitIcon = new ImageIcon("app-exit.png");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Exit", exitIcon);
        progName.add(exitAction);
        exitAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save-icon.png");
                    int askSave = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Save current image?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, saveIcon);
                    if (askSave == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        //opens save image method, then exits
                        saveImage();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        //exits without saving
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });

        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("new-image.png");
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("Open Image", newIcon);
        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save-icon.png");
                    int askSave = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Save current image?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, saveIcon);
                    if (askSave == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        //opens save image method, then asks asks for new image file
                        saveImage();
                        Picture p = new Picture();
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                        //resizes canvas to fit new image
                        frame.setSize(width(), height());
                    }
                    else {
                        //asks for new image file since user did not want to save original
                        Picture p = new Picture();
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                        //resizes canvas to fit new image
                        frame.setSize(width(), height());
                    }
                }
            });

        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save-image.png");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save Image As...", saveIcon);
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        saveAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //opens save image method
                    saveImage();
                }
            });
        ImageIcon gsIcon = new ImageIcon("grayscale-image.png");
        JMenuItem grayScale = new JMenuItem("Grayscale", gsIcon);
        editMenu.add(grayScale);
        grayScale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //grabs height and width of image, then grayscales it
                    grayscale(width(), height());
                }
            });

        ImageIcon scaleIcon = new ImageIcon("scale-image.png");
        JMenuItem scaleImg = new JMenuItem("Scale Image", scaleIcon);
        editMenu.add(scaleImg);
        scaleImg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //asks for height and width to create new image
                    ImageIcon widthIcon = new ImageIcon("LR-arrows.png");
                    String scaleWidth = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What should the new width be?", "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, widthIcon, null, null);
                    ImageIcon heightIcon = new ImageIcon("UD-arrows.png");
                    String scaleHeight = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What should the new height be?", "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, widthIcon, null, null);
                    //turns user input strings into doubles
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(scaleWidth);
                    double y = Double.parseDouble(scaleHeight);
                    //casts doubles as ints
                    int newWidth = (int)x;
                    int newHeight = (int)y;
                    //resizes frame to fit new image dimensions
                    frame.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
                    //calls scale method to resize image using given dimensions
                    scale(newWidth, newHeight);
                }
            });
        ImageIcon rotateIcon = new ImageIcon("rotate-image.png");
        JMenuItem rotateImg = new JMenuItem("Rotate Image", rotateIcon);
        editMenu.add(rotateImg);
        rotateImg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });

        //paint the frame
        frame.pack();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // convert to grayscale
    public void grayscale(int width, int height) {
        // create a grayscale image with original dimensions
        image2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

        // convert colored image to grayscale
        ColorConvertOp grayScale = new ColorConvertOp(image.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),image2.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),null);
        grayScale.filter(image,image2);
        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
        getImage();
    }

    //scales image by a given factor
    public void scale(int width, int height){
        //uses user-input dimensions to create new image
        image2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = image2.createGraphics();
        //gets new dimensions and resizes image
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight(), 0, 0, width(), height(), null);  
        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
        getImage();
    }

    //rotates the image
    public void rotate(int width, int height, int theta) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Picture p = new Picture();
        p.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code does not compile.  Is it *really* the code being used?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It should compile...I literally just copy/pasted it from my IDE. Runs perfectly. I've updated some GUI aspects since this, I'll edit the post and paste the new code in a second.

Comment: Note that we am not informed of edits to questions.  (It is a good idea to let people know an edit has happened.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Picture]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Picture{
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Edit Image");
    Container content;
    static BufferedImage image;
    BufferedImage image2;
    JLabel imageLabel;

    public Picture() {
        //asks for image file as input
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose an image file to begin:");
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        if (fileChooser.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            try {
                //reads File as image
                image = ImageIO.read(selectedFile);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid image file: " + selectedFile);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No File Selected!");
        }
    }

    public int width() {
        //returns width of present image
        int width = image.getWidth();
        return width;
    }

    public int height() {
        //returns height of present image
        int height = image.getHeight();
        return height;
    }
/*
    public void getImage() {
        this.image2 = image;
    }
*/
    public void saveImage() {
        //saves current image as JPEG
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Save this image?");
        fileChooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
        try {
            //writes new file
            ImageIO.write(this.image, "JPG", fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        catch (IOException f) {
            System.out.println("Saving failed! Could not save image.");
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        //set frame title, set it visible, etc
        content = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //add the image to the frame
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);
        frame.setContentPane(imageLabel);

        //add a menubar on the frame with a single option: saving the image
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JMenu progName = new JMenu("Edit Image");
        progName.setBackground(Color.RED);
        menuBar.add(progName);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        ImageIcon exitIcon = new ImageIcon("app-exit.png");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Exit", exitIcon);
        progName.add(exitAction);
        exitAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save-icon.png");
                    int askSave = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Save current image?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, saveIcon);
                    if (askSave == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        //opens save image method, then exits
                        saveImage();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        //exits without saving
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });

        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("new-image.png");
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("Open Image", newIcon);
        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save-icon.png");
                    int askSave = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Save current image?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, saveIcon);
                    if (askSave == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        //opens save image method, then asks asks for new image file
                        saveImage();
                        Picture p = new Picture();
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                        //resizes canvas to fit new image
                        frame.setSize(width(), height());
                    }
                    else {
                        //asks for new image file since user did not want to save original
                        Picture p = new Picture();
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                        //resizes canvas to fit new image
                        frame.setSize(width(), height());
                    }
                }
            });

        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save-image.png");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save Image As...", saveIcon);
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        saveAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //opens save image method
                    saveImage();
                }
            });
        ImageIcon gsIcon = new ImageIcon("grayscale-image.png");
        JMenuItem grayScale = new JMenuItem("Grayscale", gsIcon);
        editMenu.add(grayScale);
        grayScale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //grabs height and width of image, then grayscales it
                    grayscale(width(), height());
                }
            });

        ImageIcon scaleIcon = new ImageIcon("scale-image.png");
        JMenuItem scaleImg = new JMenuItem("Scale Image", scaleIcon);
        editMenu.add(scaleImg);
        scaleImg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //asks for height and width to create new image
                    ImageIcon widthIcon = new ImageIcon("LR-arrows.png");
                    String scaleWidth = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What should the new width be?", "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, widthIcon, null, null);
                    ImageIcon heightIcon = new ImageIcon("UD-arrows.png");
                    String scaleHeight = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What should the new height be?", "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, widthIcon, null, null);
                    //turns user input strings into doubles
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(scaleWidth);
                    double y = Double.parseDouble(scaleHeight);
                    //casts doubles as ints
                    int newWidth = (int)x;
                    int newHeight = (int)y;
                    //resizes frame to fit new image dimensions
                    frame.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
                    //calls scale method to resize image using given dimensions
                    scale(newWidth, newHeight);
                }
            });
        ImageIcon rotateIcon = new ImageIcon("rotate-image.png");
        JMenuItem rotateImg = new JMenuItem("Rotate Image", rotateIcon);
        editMenu.add(rotateImg);
        rotateImg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });

        //paint the frame
        frame.pack();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // convert to grayscale
    public void grayscale(int width, int height) {
        // create a grayscale image with original dimensions
        image2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

        // convert colored image to grayscale
        ColorConvertOp grayScale = new ColorConvertOp(image.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),image2.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),null);
        grayScale.filter(image,image2);
        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
        //getImage();
        image = image2;
    }

    //scales image by a given factor
    public void scale(int width, int height){
        //uses user-input dimensions to create new image
        image2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = image2.createGraphics();
        //gets new dimensions and resizes image
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight(), 0, 0, width(), height(), null);
        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
        //getImage();
        image = image2;
    }

    //rotates the image
    public void rotate(int width, int height, int theta) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Picture p = new Picture();
        p.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void getImage() {
        this.image2 = image;
    }

    //..............................................

    // convert to grayscale
    public void grayscale(int width, int height) {
    // create a grayscale image with original dimensions
    image2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

    // convert colored image to grayscale
    ColorConvertOp grayScale = new ColorConvertOp(image.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),image2.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),null);
    grayScale.filter(image,image2);
    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
    getImage();
}
```

ColorConvertOp.filter(BufferedImage src, BufferedImage dest)

Your grayscale method has image2 as the dest, when you call getImage() it replaces image2 with the original not settieng the original to your new image2.

Either have grayscale(int, int) return a BuffereImage or change getImage to:

```
public void getImage() {
    this.image = image2;
}
```